# Changing time from UTC to PDT

Tags: python

This is what I have:

```
pat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0000'
my_time = time.strptime(task_time, pattern)
```

But, how can I change the timezone from:

```
 my_time:
 2016-06-15 23:27:52 +0000
```

to a different timezone:

```
PDT
```

or

```
-0700
```

So the result is:

```
result = 2016-06-15 16:27:52 -0700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the python package [`arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) this simple script can be used:

```
import arrow

fmt = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z"

time = arrow.get("2016-06-15 23:27:52 +0000", fmt)
time = time.to("US/Pacific")

print(time.format(fmt))
```

`2016-06-15 16:27:52 -0700`

Install arrow with `pip install arrow`

Edit: If you do not want to use the `arrow` package:

```
import time
import calendar

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "

t = calendar.timegm(time.strptime("2016-06-15 23:27:52 +0000", fmt + "+0000"))
t -= 8 * 60 * 60

s = time.strftime(fmt + "-0700", time.gmtime(t))

print(s)
```

Note, that this is horrible code and if you use this in production you will definitely get fired from your job, so just install the `arrow` package!

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a solution without importing anything other than standard libraries.

Comment: @Empario This is not possible without any packages

Comment: some solution by using time, calendar, datetime packages